# Iterating Over List, Combining Quantities

Tags: python, loops

I have created a simple program to take a list of simplified sku's and qty's and add it to another list. However if the sku is already in the second list I would like to just increment the qty as opposed to adding a copy. I have tried a few different `for` loops and I haven't been able to get it to work.

```
myList = [["a",1],["c",1],["a",1]] #[sku, qty]
newList = [["null",0]] #placeholder value so second for loop functions

for eachItem in myList:
    for eachNew in newList:
        if eachItem[0] == eachNew[0]: # if sku is in list increment qty
            eachNew[1] += eachItem[1]
            myList.remove(eachItem)
        else:
            newList.append([eachItem[0], eachItem[1]]) #else add the sku to the list
            myList.remove(eachItem)

#remove null place holder
for eachItem in newList:
    if eachItem[0] == "null":
        newList.remove(eachItem)

for eachItem in newList:
    print(eachItem)
```

My desired output would be:

```
['a', 2]
['c', 1]
```

EDIT: I just realized I wasn't clear enough in my OP. I don't want to count the number of times a sku appears I want to add all the quantities. It is possible that there will be quantities of more than one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not as elegant as pandas and I couldn't figure out collections.Counter so, this is more along the lines of what you were doing. It builds a dictionary and then builds the list again with a comprehension.

```
mylist = [["a",1],["c",1],["a",1]]
newlist = [["null",0]]

mydict = {}
for i in mylist+newlist:
    if i[0] in mydict:
        mydict[i[0]]+=i[1]
    elif i[0] != 'null':
        mydict[i[0]]=i[1]

print [[x,mydict[x]] for x in mydict]

[['a', 2], ['c', 1]]
```

Comment: Why are you adding newList and myList?

Comment: @Selecsosi Because they said "I have created a simple program to take a list of simplified sku's and qty's and add it to another list. "

Comment: newList = [["null",0]] #placeholder value so second for loop functions

Comment: @Selecsosi I don't know what to tell you. My interpretation of that is that `[["null",0]]` is a place holder not representing the actual data that might be there. Perhaps they did not mean that, but they did accept it. Not an issue really. If it isn't needed, I am sure they can delete all occurrences of the second unneeded list and it will work just like your code, now that you fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/basics.html) from the pandas libray like so:

```
import pandas as pd
myList = [["a",1],["c",1],["a",1]]
myList = pd.Series(myList)
mylist.value_counts().to_list()
```

would yeild:

```
[['a',2],['c',1]]
```

like this example

```
In [83]: data

array([4, 6, 6, 1, 2, 1, 0, 5, 3, 2, 4, 3, 1, 3, 5, 3, 0, 0, 4, 4, 6, 1, 0,
       4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 5, 6, 3, 1, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 0, 1,
       2, 4, 5, 5])

In [84]: s = Series(data)

In [85]: s.value_counts()

3    11
2     9
4     8
1     8
5     5
0     5
6     4
dtype: int64
```

The programming behind it is much more efficient than a for loop because the basis is written in C. You can use the `to_list()` method, `mylist.value_counts().to_list()`, to get it exactly to your desired output.

## * this code is untested

Answer (score 1):

Look into the the `collections.Counter` class in the python library documentation.  It won't require any loops.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

This is a dict, that maps a sku to a quantity, that will allow you to aggregate values together and keep track of what you have already counted

Dont over complicate it

```
myList = [["a",1],["c",1],["a",1]] #[sku, qty]

counter_dict = {}  #schema {"sku": quantity:int }
for eachItem in myList:
    if eachItem[0] in counter_dict:
        counter_dict[eachItem[0]] += eachItem[1]
    else:
        counter_dict[eachItem[0]] = eachItem[1]


for key in counter_dict.keys():
    print([key, counter_dict[key]])
```

Comment: I think you meant to make each `= eachItem[0]` `= eachItem[1]`